# Define Geometry Values on XYZM Coordinates

Tags: sql-server, geometry, coordinates

I am working with SQL Server.

How do you define the X, Y, Z & M values in Geometry point types?

I have a table called config with the following columns:

```
[PointNumber] ,[Epoch] ,[BaseEasting] ,[BaseNorthing] ,[BaseElevation]
```

If I use the following query, it gives me the geometry value in Easting and Northing:

```
    SELECT [PointNumber] ,[Epoch] ,[BaseEasting] ,[BaseNorthing] ,[BaseElevation] 
    ,geometry::Point([BaseEasting], [BaseNorthing], 4326) as GeomValue
    FROM [config]
```

I know if I use the following query it will return the x, y, z & m values specified in the select statement:

```
SELECT geometry::Parse('POINT(4 5 6 3.5)')
```

My question is how do I use my

```
[Epoch] ,[BaseEasting] ,[BaseNorthing] ,[BaseElevation]
```

instead of the

```
('POINT(4 5 6 3.5)')
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search turned up this MSDN page describing `AsTextZM()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933810.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 .

I *think* then your parameters would line up:

`[BaseEasting] = X`

`[BaseNorthing] = Y`

`[BaseElevation] = Z`

`[Epoch] = M` <-- This is the only one I can't find a definition for; I'm not familiar with "epoch" and if that is considered "measure" or not.

So maybe something like:

```
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' 
+ [BaseEasting] + ' '
+ [BaseNorthing] + ' '
+ [BaseElevation] + ' '
+ [Epoch] + ')', 0);
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, epoch is the m value, sorry I should have made that clearer. Your soulution does not work, I get the error: Msg 14, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: You should be able to convert a varchar to float via `CONVERT(float, myVarcharValue)`.  Do you have sample values for your fields so that we can construct a specific example?